# Looking for Clarification on how this "For-Loop" works

Tags: python, for-loop

I'm a complete beginner to programming so forgive me for my naivete.

I wanted to make a program in Python that lets me print a given `N` number of prime numbers, where `N` is inputted by the user. I searched a little on "for/while" loops and did some tinkering. I ran a program I saw online and modified it to suit the problem. Here is the code:

```
i = 1

print("Hi! Let's print the first N prime numbers.")
nPrimes = int(input("Enter your N: "))

counter =  0

while True:
    c = 0 #another initialization
    for x in range (1, (i + 1)):
        a = i % x # "a" is a new variable that got introduced.
        if a == 0:
            c = c + 1
    if c == 2:
        print(i, end = "  ")
        counter = counter + 1
        if counter > = nPrimes: #if it reaches the number input, the loop will end.
            break
    i = i+1

print(":  Are your", nPrimes, "prime number/s!")
print()
print("Thanks for trying!")
```

This should be able to print the amount of prime numbers the user so likes. It is a working code, though I am having difficulty trying to understand it. It seems that the variable `c` is important in deciding whether or not to print the variable `i` (which in our case is the supposed prime number during that interval).

We do `c + 1` to `c` every time our variable `a` has a remainder of `0` in `a = i % x`. Then, if `c` reaches 2, the current variable `i` is printed, and variable `c` re-initializes itself to 0 once a prime number has been found and printed.

This I can comprehend, but I get confused once the numbers of `i` get to values 4 and onwards. *How is 4 skipped by the program and not printed when it has 2+ factors in the range that makes its remainder equal to zero? Wouldn't `c == 2` for 4 and thus print 4? *And how would the program continue to the next number, 5? (Given that variable `N` is a large enough input).

Any clarifications would be greatly appreciated. Thank you so much!

Comment: c is important because every prime number X is dividable by 2 number from 1 to X, which are 1 and X. basically by going from  1 --> X you are dividing X by these, and if divisible, i.e `i%x == 0` then c is incremented. Any prime number should have c = 2 because of 1 and the prime number are the dividers. Any other number that has a bigger c is not printed. Cheers.

Comment: For example, for number 4. c starts at 0. 4%1 = 0 --> c=1 then 4%2 = 0 --> c=2 then 4%4 = 0 --> c=3. Already bigger than 2.

Comment: I see @HadiFarah ! So, 4 couldn't have been printed because its c was more than just 2. While 5, 7, 9... are c==2. Big thanks! I might have been overthinking it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number) we know:

> A prime number (or a prime) is a natural number greater than 1 that cannot be formed by multiplying two smaller natural numbers.

So to find a prime, is to find a natural number, aka an integer, which can only be **exactly divided** by 1 or itself. This is called *Approach of Definition* to find primes.

Hence, the following loop traverses through all integers from 1 to `i`,
and it counts how many times the integer `i` can be **exactly divided** by them.

```
for x in range (1, (i + 1)):
    a = i % x # "a" is a new variable that got introduced.
    if a == 0:
        c = c + 1
```

And later you judge if the integer `i` can only be **exactly divided** by 1 and itself.
If true, you got a prime;
otherwise you just keep on.

```
if c == 2:
    print(i, end = "  ")
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter > = nPrimes: #if it reaches the number input, the loop will end.
        break
```

---

Meanwhile, you can improve this prime searching algorithm a little bit by changing `i = 1` to `i = 2` in the beginning and adding an `if` statement:

```
# Start from 2 instead of 1
# and end at `i - 1` instead of `i`
for x in range (2, i):
    a = i % x # "a" is a new variable that got introduced.
    if a == 0:
        c = c + 1

    # Abandon the loop
    # because an integer with factors other than 1 and itself
    # is unevitably a composite number, not a prime
    if c > 0:
        break

if c == 0:
    print(i, end = "  ")
    counter = counter + 1
    if counter >= nPrimes: #if it reaches the number input, the loop will end.
        break
```

This twist improves the efficiency of your program because you avoid unnecessary and meaningless amount of work.

---

To prevent potential infinite loop resulting from `while` expression,
you should replace `while True:` with `while counter < nPrimes:`. And the code turns out to be like this:

```
#if it reaches the number input, the loop will end.
while counter < nPrimes:
    c = 0 #another initialization

    # Start from 2 instead of 1
    # and end at `i - 1` instead of `i`
    for x in range (2, i):
        a = i % x # "a" is a new variable that got introduced.
        if a == 0:
            c = c + 1

        # Abandon the loop
        # because an integer with factors other than 1 and itself
        # is unevitably a composite number, not a prime
        if c > 0:
            break

    if c == 0:
        print(i, end = "  ")
        counter = counter + 1

    i = i + 1
```

---

If you want to read more about how to improve your program's efficiency in finding primes, read [this code in C language](https://github.com/donizyo/PrimeSeeker/blob/master/main.c). :P

Comment: Thank you @KaiserKatze , so as I see from your clarification, even if a composite number does reach c==2, it will not stop there, since there are more numbers it is divisible with, and thus it won't be printed. I appreciate your insight a lot. The code you modified is a lot more simpler, too!

Comment: @Sorz You are right about `while`, I mean, one should never use `while True:`, just in case of infinite loops. Thus I'm going to update my answer and amend this `while` loop a little bit.

Answer (score 0):

c in this case is used to count the number of numbers that divide evenly into i.

for example, if `i = 8`: 8 is divisible by 1, 2, 4, and 8. so `c = 4` since there are 4 things that divide evenly into it

if `i = 5`: 5 is divisible by 1 and 5. so `c = 2` since there are 2 numbers that divide evenly into it

if `i = 4` (where you seem to be confused): 4 is divisible by 1, 2, and 4. so `c = 3`, not 2.

Comment: Thank you so much! I suppose I was confused because of my overthinking. I overlooked the operator as well for c==2 and thought of it as anything equal to 2 or more. Now it is clear to me :)